# Is the exact expression for $x_{2n} ,x_{2n+1}$ solvable or limit can be solved without that?

Tags: vector-analysis

Given : $$
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Let } \quad \begin{array}{l}
\bar{a}=\bar{i}+2 \bar{j}+3 \bar{k} \\
\bar{b}=2 \bar{i}+3 \bar{j}+4 \bar{k} \\
\bar{c}=4 \bar{i}+\bar{j} \\
\bar{d}=5 \bar{i}+2 \bar{j}+\bar{k}
\end{array}\\
\text { Now consider a sequence of vectors given by : }\\
\bar{x}_{1}=\bar{a},\\
\begin{aligned}
\bar{x}_{2} &=\bar{c}+\left(\frac{\left(\bar{x}_{1}-\bar{c}\right) \cdot \bar{d}}{|\bar{d}|^{2}}\right) \bar{d}, \quad \bar{x}_{3}=\bar{a}+\left(\frac{\left(\bar{x}_{2}-\bar{a}\right) \cdot \bar{b}}{|\bar{b}|^{2}}\right) \bar{b}, \\
\bar{x}_{4} &=\bar{c}+\left(\frac{\left(\bar{x}_{3}-\bar{c}\right) \cdot \bar{d}}{|\bar{d}|^{2}}\right) \bar{d}, \quad \bar{x}_{5}=\bar{a}+\left(\frac{\left(\bar{x}_{4}-\bar{a}\right) \cdot \bar{b}}{|\bar{b}|^{2}}\right) \bar{b}, \\
\bar{x}_{6} &=\bar{c}+\left(\frac{\left(\bar{x}_{5}-\bar{c}\right) \cdot \bar{d}}{|\bar{d}|^{2}}\right) \bar{d} \text { and so on. }  find\\
l_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bar{x}_{2 n}=
\end{aligned}
\end{array}
$$ My progress: I got two relation between $(\bar x_{2n+1} ,\bar x_{2n} )$ and $(\bar x_{2n},\bar x_{2n-1})$ by geomtric interpretation that is $(\bar x_{2n+1} -\bar x_{2n}) \cdot \bar b = 0$ and $(\bar x_{2n} - \bar x_{2n-1} )\cdot\bar  d = 0,$ now how to solve for exact $\bar x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ , or there is no need to calculate it can be solved without that for limit ?

Comment: A key observation might be $\bar b+\bar d=\bar a+\bar c.$

Comment: U meant b+c = a+d isnt ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Note that by limit exists it would be of form ai +bj+ck

Comment: @thomas andrews it was not of much help to solve that recurrence

Comment: The sequence alternates between being points on two lines, $\bar c+t\bar d$ for the evens, $\bar a+t\bar b$ one the other. The two lines intersect at $\bar a-\bar b=\bar c-\bar d.$

Comment: Thanks this was what i needed

Answer (score 1):

These points alternate between the two lines, $\bar c+t\bar d$ for the evens, $\bar a+t\bar b$ for the odds. The two lines intersect at $\bar a-\bar b=\bar c-\bar d.$

Let $$\bar y_n=\bar x_n-(\bar a-\bar b)=\bar x_n-(\bar c-\bar d).$$

Then $$\begin{align}y_{2n}&=\bar x_{2n}-(\bar c-\bar d)
\\&=\bar c+\left(\frac{(\bar y_{2n-1}+(\bar c-\bar d)-\bar c)\cdot \bar d}{|\bar d|^2}\right)\bar d-(\bar c-\bar d)\\
&=\bar d+\left(\frac{\bar y_{2n-1}\cdot\bar d-|\bar d|^2}{|\bar d|^2}\right)\bar d
\\&=\left(\frac{\bar y_{2n-1}\cdot \bar d}{|\bar d|^2}\right)\bar d\tag1
\end{align} $$
and similarly $$\bar y_{2n+1}=\left(\frac{\bar y_{2n}\cdot \bar b}{|\bar b|^2}\right)\bar b\tag 2$$

Now $$\bar y_{2n-1}=\alpha_n \bar b\\\bar y_{2n}=\beta_n\bar d$$ for sequences $\alpha_n,\beta_n,$ with $\alpha_1=1.$ Use (1) and (2) to find a recurrence for $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n.$

Or you can notice that the formula (1) is the orthogonal projection of $y_{2n-1}$ onto the subspace generated by $\bar d$ and (2) is the orthogonal projection of $y_{2n}$ onto the subspace generated by $\bar b.$

Comment: I see , for solving by first method of yours (orthogonal one is second method and i tried this which gave me those two relations (x_2n+1 -x_2n).b= 0 and....) u meant checking the pattern? As what i thought of recurrence relation which i could solve would be x_2n+1 = zx_2n+e ,but how to deal with dot product as its not what i wanted as expression of recurrence? And the two relations i got it is of not much use to solve recurrence?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Did you follow my suggestion to “Use (1) and (2) to come up with a recursion for $\alpha_n,\beta_n?$” if so, what did you get? Show you have made an effort before I spell things out even more.

Comment: I got it now by your both methods @ThomasAndrews so my relations which i got (i.e. x_2n+1-x2n and another one ) is not of any use at all ?